# Getting blank screen when switching between activities

Tags: android

I am working on an app , where I am switching between two activities. When control is inside onStart of second activity , there is screen drawing and processing logic being handled.Because of this , when switching between the two activities happens, there is a blank screen that comes up.

Along with this , i also need to render a live video feed in background of my activities/app

What could be the best way to deal with this?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a blank screen it could be because your activity is setting a new contentview but it hasn't been processed properly. Does it ever load completely? If it's just that it's black at the beginning and then renders. Try setting the contentview at the end of your switching in onCreate. This will make it remain on the first activity and avoiding switching views on till everything is loaded.

With regards your second question. Is the live video feed from the Camera?

If it is, set the camera view in the background, make a transparent LinearLayout (or whatever your layout is) over it and then put your various views there.

Your question doesn't have enough specific information to get an accurate idea as to what you're talking about, if my answer doesn't address your problem please respond with elaboration and some code! :-)

Comment: Thanks.@ First qustion-yes,my activity takes time to load , but gets rendered in some time.So its black in the begining and then renders.You are telling to place setContentView just before exiting from onCreate()?Let me try this.@ Second question: Its a live feed , anfd I have made the parent layout transparent(Using VISIBILITY)

Comment: Yes, set the setcontentview after your activity finishes "loading". Take a look at progress bars if you want to let the user know http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.homepage_layout);
profilelist = (WheelView)findViewById(R.id.homepageList); 
profileListName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homepageName);
previousView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.previousWheelView);     
Intent prevIntent  = getIntent();
profileName   = prevIntent.getStringExtra("name");        if (!ImageHolder.isStackEmpty()) {bitMap = ImageHolder.getImageFromStack().getBitMapData();} This is the peice of code that I have written inside OnCreate() , and setting content view in end i don't think is a solution.I do not want to show progress dialogs(no network calls)

Comment: Have you tried setting contentview at the end and not at the start?

Comment: I got NullPointerException , as it did not identify the layout attributes that i was fetching with findViewById